# How do I configure nginx's embedded Perl to use Perl modules?

Tags: nginx, perl

I have configured nginx to use a specific version of Perl.

```
$ sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/0.8.54
built by gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
TLS SNI support disabled
configure arguments: --with-debug --with-http_ssl_module --with-md5=auto/lib/md5 --with-sha1=auto/lib/sha1 --with-perl=/opt/perl/bin/perl --with-http_gzip_static_module --user=apache --group=apache --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/client/ --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/proxy/ --prefix=/opt/nginx
```

I created two Perl modules based on [EmbeddedPerlMinifyJS](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxEmbeddedPerlMinifyJS): MinifyJS.pm and MinifyCSS.pm which are in the same directory as the nginx.conf file. Inside the http section of the config file I have the following four lines:

```
perl_require JavaScript/Minifier.pm;
perl_require CSS/Minifier.pm;
perl_require MinifyJS.pm;
perl_require MinifyCSS.pm;
```

In my server section I have the following:

```
location ~ \.js$ {
    perl MinifyJS::handler;
}

location ~ \.css$ {
    perl MinifyCSS::handler;
}
```

When I start nginx, I get an error about "perl_require".

```
$ sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
[emerg]: unknown directive "perl_require" in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:31
```

So how do I configure nginx to use the embedded Perl?

(BTW, "perl_modules" also throws an unknown directive.)

Answer (score 2):

I saw the answer immediately after posting. You have to add `--with-http_perl_module` (and possibly `--with-perl_modules_path`) when running `configure`.

This was found at [EmbeddedPerlModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/EmbeddedPerlModule) in the section entitled "Building Module at Compile-time".

Comment: Mmm, how do you re-configure perl like this? I'm getting the same error - but I'm unsure of how to tweak Perl. I installed via apt-get, so its a bit new to me :)

Comment: @AndrewNewby I compiled Perl from source code.